# Why i am not able to play mp3 file in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget, android-ndk

I have Implemented this code to play the Sound file available in res/drawable/testing123.mp3 file.
The code is :

```
 public void playSound()
    {
        boolean mStartPlaying = true;
        if (mStartPlaying==true) 
        {
//          String word = wordValue.getText().toString();
            String file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
            String sound = file+"/testing123.mp3";
            //System.out.println("Before Allocation file is: "+file);
            //rePlay.setText("Stop");
            mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            try 
            {
                mPlayer.setDataSource(sound);
                mPlayer.prepare();
                mPlayer.start();
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
           //   stopPlaying();
            //rePlay.setText("Replay");
            mPlayer.release();
            mPlayer = null;
        }
        mStartPlaying = !mStartPlaying;
    }
```

But i am not able to play it.
The Sound file is in the res/drawable/testing123.mp3

So Please help me, why i am not able to play that file ?
Thanks.

Comment: are there any errors or do you just not hear any sound?

Comment: I am not hearing any sound. . .

Comment: Sounds like a problem with permissions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my applications I put audio files in the /res/raw folder. For example I have an mp3 file used for notifications called "notify.mp3" in my raw folder and I can access it by

`Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.darrenmowat.boothr/" + R.raw.notify);`

You could then use

`mPlayer.setDataSource(context, uri);`

to set the data source.

Comment: Ok Let me try. is it able to play on Activity call ?

Comment: Well if you have it set up to start playing when the activity is created it should start playing. I was really just pointing out you were accessing the file wrongly :p

Comment: Still i am not able to play the Song why ?

Comment: Ok. I forget to change the package. Now i have change it and it works great.

Answer (score 1):

```
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer.create(context, URI);
player.start();
```

This should be enought, just ensure that your URI is correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
in my case it works.i add external storage permission.dont know whether it is needed.you first have to copy the music file to sdCard.and check ur mplayer is initiated or not.

public void playSound()
    {
        MediaPlayer mPlayer;
        mPlayer=new MediaPlayer();
        boolean mStartPlaying = true;
        if (mStartPlaying==true) 
        {


                String file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();


                try {

                    mPlayer.setDataSource(file+"/30.mp3"); mPlayer.prepare(); mPlayer.start();
                    ;
                    } 
                catch (Exception e) 
                    {e.printStackTrace(); } }
        else { 
     mStartPlaying = !mStartPlaying; }
}
```

Comment: forgot to tell change songs name in setDataSource to the appropriate file name

Answer (score 1):

your problem is the file permission.

By default, when writing to an FileOutputStream, you end up with rw-,---,--- type of permission (600). MediaPlayer will not be able to play the file unless you give it "read permission" to "others": at least rw-,---,r-- (604).

I recommend 644 (rw,r,r) and you can use the following command to do so:

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 644 " + PATH_TO_YOUR_FILE);

You should then be able to play the saved media file